# RelatedTo with users

Tags: templating, relations, usermodel

The RelatedTo function keeps puzzeling me. I got it working with categories, but now I want to do something in reverse with users. But I don't fully understand the RelatedTo function.

I have a channel called "downloads". I also have some users in the back-end. I have added a custom field to the user section called "selectDownloads". This field is a relatedEntry field where the admin can select entries from the downloads channel.
Now I want to list all downloads in my template that the current logged in user may see (so the entries that were selected when creating the user).

I read the docs multiple times allready and with some luck and trial and error I got it working on categories. But there I loop through all my products and relate them to a targetSource which is my category by a field that is part of my products channel.
In this case however, I want to loop through all my downloads, related to a field that is part of my users section (instead of my downloads channel). So the relation is different.

A more dummy proof explanation with some examples of the RelatedTo function would be welcome. I never know which elements I should address:

```
 {% set ingredients = craft.entries.section('ingredients').relatedTo({
     sourceElement: cocktail,
     field: 'ingredients' }) %}
```

**`sourceElement` or `targetElement`:**

Is this a section or field you have to give in?

**`field`:**

Is that a field from the ingredients section or the cocktail section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('downloads').relatedTo(currentUser) %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

This is essentially returning an `ElementCriteriaModel` of reverse related entries sorted by entry date by default. You can also access the related entries through the field itself:

```
{% for entry in currentUser.selectDownloads %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

This will loop through the related entries in the order they are sorted in the CP.

But to answer your other questions. `sourceElement` and `targetElement` can be `elements` of any element type: entry, category, asset, user, globalSet, tag, etc are all elements. `sourceElement` simply refers to which is the source of the relationship; and `targetElement` is what it's related to. `field` further specifies that you only want to match a specific field rather than using any relationship defined in any field (if you have 2 or more `entries` fields defined in a channel that are used for different purposes for example).

Comment: My God. Craft is so wonderfully simple! I always look to far for an answer. Love it!